# OS/EXEC Не запускает бинарник

Tags: linux, golang

Необходимо запустить c помощью программы на GoLang бинарник. Для этого я сделал ссылку на данный бинарник в sbin

```
sudo ln /home/pi/gsm-ppp/stopPPP /usr/sbin/
```

на GoLang выполняю

```
c1 = exec.Command("stopPPP")
err := c1.Start()
log.Println(err)
```

и программа выводит

> fork/exec /usr/sbin/stopPPP: exec format error

ОС linux

Comment: скорей всего `stopPPP` собран под другую архитектуру... вручную, я подозреваю, он тоже не запускается?

Comment: Запускается, если вручную

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему запуск идёт на Pi, если я прав то можно попробовать собрать вашу программу запустив в консоли с исходником *.go:

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GOARM=7 go build
```